# How does method inlining work for auto-properties in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, jit

I'm reading [Effective C# (Second Edition)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-covers-4-0-Specific-Development/dp/0321658701/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1301263706&sr=1-1) and it talks about *method inlining*.

I understand the principle, but I don't see how it would work based on the 2 examples in the book. The book says:

> Inlining means to substitute the body of a function for the function call.

Fair enough, so if I have a method, and its call:

```
public string SayHiTo(string name)
{
    return "Hi " + name;
}

public void Welcome()
{
    var msg = SayHiTo("Sergi");
}
```

the JIT compiler might (will?) inline it to:

```
public void Welcome()
{
    var msg = "Hi " + "Sergi";
}
```

Now, with these two examples (verbatim from the book):

**Example 1**

```
// readonly name property
public string Name { get; private set; }

// access:
string val = Obj.Name;
```

**Example 2**

```
string val = "Default Name";
if(Obj != null)
    val = Obj.Name;
```

The book mentions the code but doesn't go any further into how they might be inlined. How would the JIT compiler inline these 2 examples?

Comment: The question is currently very broad, answering the following would help: 
What is the book stating the resulting inlining will be?  Why do you think it will not work?

Comment: by compiler you mean JITer compiler?

Comment: @earlNameless, @lukas - The book mentions these two examples and doesn't state further *how* it will be inlined, hence my question. Yes, I mean the JIT compiler. I've updated my question to make these points clear, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automatic properties are syntactic sugar for field-backed properties.

Properties are syntactic sugar for setter and/or getter methods.

Hence the code you give is more or less equivalent to:

```
private string _name;
public string get_Name()
{
  return _name;
}
private void set_Name(string value)
{
  _name = value;
}
```

Then `string val = Obj.Name` becomes equivalent to `string val = Obj.get_Name()` which can be inlined to `string val = Obj._name`.

Likewise the code

```
string val = "Default Name";
if(Obj != null)
  val = Obj.Name;
```

Is is equivalent to:

```
string val = "Default Name";
if(Obj != null)
  val = Obj.get_Name();
```

Which can be inlined to:

```
string val = "Default Name";
if(Obj != null)
  val = Obj._name;
```

Note that `private` and `public` apply to compilation, not to execution, so while the fact that the backing field is private would make `Obj._name` illegal outside of the class in question, the equivalent code produced by inlining, is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

**Hypothetically** speaking, inlining here would unwrap the body of `get_Name()` that's auto-generated by the compiler, which simply returns a private backing field. It might look something like this:

```
string val = Obj.k__BackingField;
```

Comment: Indeed. In practice of course, the C# compiler does not do any inlining, which is instead deferred to the JIT. At the JIT level, there is no longer a difference between method calls and property accesses – both can be inlined similarly.

Comment: @Hans I have no idea whether it would actually do that in this case, so it's hypothetical for me.

Answer (score 2):

Inlining takes places **after accessibility checks**, so it can optimize code in ways that you can't with simple source substitution.